# Synchronous Buck Converter Mathematics

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, rectifier, converter, synchronous

Ive been trying to find a mathematical explanation on how a Synchronous Buck converter maintains continuous operation under ideal steady state conditions. I understand the underlying concept but i want to know how i can explain it mathematically (ideal case).

[image]

Comment: if you're looking for an ideal case and not concerned about switching losses / behavior then its exactly the same as a regular buck converter except your 1-Duty cycle is now your on time for the lower switch instead of the diode path. every single equation would still apply, again ideally.

Comment: Could you please provide this explanation mathematically possibly ?

Comment: You can have a look at the answer I gave [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509898/where-does-the-negative-inductor-current-go-during-ccm-at-no-load-in-synchronous/509906#509906). There is nothing mysterious, it is just that the controlled low-side switch keeps conducting while the inductor current is zero (the diode would spontaneously block) and brings the inductor current negative until the high-switch turns back on again. In a no-load situation, the inductor average current is zero and it peaks above and below ground.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest and easiest switching converter to understand: -

- The input voltage is modulated by the switch's duty cycle to produce an average value that corresponds with the required output voltage.
- The LC acts as a low pass filter and converts the modulated duty cycle from above into a steady DC value.

There are mathematics involved if you want them to be but the words are simple enough and 100% accurate in defining the operation of two switches selecting either Vin or 0 volts.

If you want the maths of the LC filter then there are plenty of [resources](http://www.stades.co.uk/index.html#2nd_order_low_pass_filter_design) for this and a [calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RLC%20LPF.html#RLC_low_pass_filter_type_2) to help you visualize things. The theory is not that involved so I've not bothered to repeat it here but, if you need it or help with it please ask.