# Synchronous buck - "Inverse" current in the lower switch

Tags: mosfet, dc-dc-converter, buck, igbt, synchronous

I am referring to the typical **synchronous buck** architecture:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn21X5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The cycle starts with M1 conducting and inductor current increasing (*I_L > 0*). Then, M1 is turned OFF, and, with some dead-time, M2 is turned ON (driving its gate).
During the dead-time, the body diode D2 conducts. Then, once M2 is "completely" ON, *I_L > 0* will flow into M2 from Source to Drain.

My questions are:

1. "Usual" current direction in **MOSFET** is from drain to source (*Ids > 0*); here **M2** works in the opposite direction (*Ids < 0*). As far as I know, the MOSFET is theoretically a "symmetric" device, apart from the fact that usually the Body is internally connected to the source (leading to the usual drawing with diode in anti-parallel) and that for manufacturing reasons, drain and source are not the same. In this *Ids < 0* condition, **is *Rds,on* the same**? How should the **gate be biased**? Usually *Vgs* is considered from gate to source, being source the terminal at the lowest voltage. Here the **drain** is at the lowest voltage.
2. Does this work with **IGBTs**? I mean, if M2 was an IGBT, **can the current flow from emitter to collector**? Or, instead, only D2 conducts while *I_L > 0*?

In other terms, what is not clear to me, both for the **IGBT** and the **MOSFET**, is the **four-quadrant characteristic** in the I and III quadrant.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509898/where-does-the-negative-inductor-current-go-during-ccm-at-no-load-in-synchronous/509906#509906). You can also have a look at this old [application note](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/an1520-d.pdf) from the MOT days. In reverse mode, the body diode ensures the conduction for a small period of time (the inserted deadtime) and then the MOSFET is turned on by the controller with 0 V across its terminal since the diode conducts.

Comment: So assuming that the intrinsic body diode of M2 is up to the task (carrying L current and transient voltage at switching speed), D2 and even D1 could be redundant.

Comment: @rdtsc You rarely see FETs with external diodes in this topology.  Sometimes people try to use a Schottky diode to reduce conduction (during deadtime) and reverse recovery losses, but mostly people rely on the body diodes of the FETs.

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I didn't specify that D1 and D2 in the schematic are intended to explicitly model MOSFET body diodes, just for the sake of completness. However, the question is about source-drain conduction of MOSFET and emitter-collector of IGBT.

Comment: @VerbalKint I had already read your answer to that question, it was really useful to me. Thanks also for the App note. But what about IGBTs?

Comment: @AlessioCaligiuri, no, IGBTs cannot be used in synchronous rectification circuits as they can't conduct in the 3rd quadrant as a MOSFET or GaN would. This [article](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/discrete-power-semis/article/21196985/igbts-frequently-asked-questions-faqs) gives more details while this [AN](https://gansystems.com/newsroom/common-misconceptions-about-the-mosfet-body-diode/) gives interesting data for GaNs.